# Avoid product variation purchases when stock quantity is below 3 in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, stock, product-variations

When a product variation has an inventory of '0' it is not purchasable
When a product variation has an inventory <= 2 it is not purchasable
When a product variation has an inventory >2 it is purchasable
I have set the availability but I am having a problem setting woocommerce_is_purchasable based on the availability or on the variations' inventory level

```
// Change In Stock Text
function filter_woocommerce_get_availability( $availability, $product ) {       
    // Managing stock is activated
    if ( $product->managing_stock() ) {
        // Stock quantity
        $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
        
        // Compare
        if ( $stock_quantity <= 0 ) {
            $availability['availability'] = __('OUT OF STOCK', 'woocommerce' );
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity > 0 && $stock_quantity <= 2 ) {
            $availability['availability'] = __('Available in Store Only', 'woocommerce' );
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');          
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 3 )  {
            $availability['availability'] = __('IN STOCK', 'woocommerce' );
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_true'); 
        }
    } else {
        // In stock
        if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
            $availability['availability'] = __('4. Turned on, In stock', 'woocommerce' );      
        } else {
            $availability['availability'] = __('5. Turned off, Out of stock', 'woocommerce' );              
        }
    }
    return $availability;
}
```

Comment: You should change stock after client make a purchase which makes more sense to me. So use woocommerce_thankyou action hook to check order items loop the products and check theyr stock and based on theyr stock apply your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use a filter hook inside another filter hook.

Note: For variations, the filter hook is: `woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable`

Try instead:

```php
// Change In Stock Text
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'filter_woocommerce_get_availability', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_get_availability( $availability, $product ) {       
    // Managing stock is activated
    if ( $product->managing_stock() ) {
        $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity(); // Get stock quantity
        
        if ( $stock_quantity <= 0 ) {
            $availability['availability'] = __('OUT OF STOCK', 'woocommerce' );
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity > 0 && $stock_quantity <= 2 ) {
            $availability['availability'] = __('Available in Store Only', 'woocommerce' );       
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 3 )  {
            $availability['availability'] = __('IN STOCK', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    } else {
        if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
            $availability['availability'] = __('4. Turned on, In stock', 'woocommerce' );      
        } else {
            $availability['availability'] = __('5. Turned off, Out of stock', 'woocommerce' );              
        }
    }
    return $availability;
}

// Manage purchasable
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'filter_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'filter_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
function filter_is_purchasable( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    $stock_qty = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $stock_qty > 0 && $stock_qty <= 2 ) {
        return false;
    }
    return  $is_purchasable;
}
```

It should better work.

Comment: Thanks you Loric - that works exactly as needed.